# implode arrays in loop foreach but the result is double php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get data from an array according to the code of the item above. but the array that I made actually produces a double result. the data array that I can only fit is the item

```
$query       = "SELECT IDBRG,Disc FROM $RTL.tmasterbarang1 WHERE IDBRG IN (1167646,1170635,1170634)";
 // echo  $query;
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$a      = $row['IDBRG'];
$b      = $row['Disc'];
$arr1   = str_split($b);

foreach($arr1 as $x=>$x_value)
{
  echo "<br>";

  $queryz   = "SELECT CAT_DISC_NBR FROM $RTL.cat_disc_test WHERE FLR_NBR = 1 AND CAT_DISC_CD = '".$x_value."' ";
  // echo $queryz;
  $resultz  = mysqli_query($connect, $queryz);
  $rowz     = mysqli_fetch_array($resultz);
  $elements[] = $rowz['CAT_DISC_NBR'];

}
  echo $all =  implode(',', $elements);
}


result of print_r($arr1)."<br>";

1. Array ( [0] => Y [1] => 4 [2] => S [3] => V ) 
2. Array ( [0] => Y [1] => 4 [2] => S [3] => V )  
3. Array ( [0] => Y [1] => G [2] => 3 ) 

// and the each of array have value  Y=69, 4=39, S=66, V=66, G=51, 3=38

echo $all =  implode(',', $elements);
69,39,63,66
69,39,63,66,69,39,63,66
69,39,63,66,69,39,63,66,69,51,38

// i want it should be
69,39,63,66
69,39,63,66
69,51,38
```

Comment: run after while loop i think, outside `while` loop

Comment: when run after while it will be 69,39,63,66,69,39,63,66,69,51,38,I want to get it separately

Answer (score 2):

When you add the data at

```
$elements[] = $rowz['CAT_DISC_NBR'];
```

this just keeps on adding data and the `$elements` array is never cleared out, so the next loop will just keep on adding data to the results of the last loop.

You need something like...

```
$a      = $row['IDBRG'];
$b      = $row['Disc'];
$arr1   = str_split($b);
$elements = [];    // Reset list
```

Comment: I tried for hours but it turned out like this. thank you expert. it's new knowledge for me

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are adding data to elements every time and you never set it to empty again. You should empty the elements array before each foreach loop:

```
$elements=[];
foreach($arr1 as $x=>$x_value)
{
  echo "<br>";

  $queryz   = "SELECT CAT_DISC_NBR FROM $RTL.cat_disc_test WHERE FLR_NBR = 1 AND CAT_DISC_CD = '".$x_value."' ";
  // echo $queryz;
  $resultz  = mysqli_query($connect, $queryz);
  $rowz     = mysqli_fetch_array($resultz);
  $elements[] = $rowz['CAT_DISC_NBR'];

}
```

Comment: I tried for hours but it turned out like this. thank you expert. it's new knowledge for me

Comment: yes this is proper solution, one more solution is that, u can rearrange your array like `$elements[$x_value][]` and implode as u need. @BenyBondBanjarnahor